# meteor add sweet alert for delete

Tags: meteor, sweetalert

I dont know where and how to put remove line:

```
Clanovi.remove(this._id);
```

in sweet alert, I tried like this:

```
'click .btn-danger'()
{

    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm){
      if (isConfirm) {
        Clanovi.remove(this._id);
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
      } 
      else
      {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
      }
    });

}
```

This does not work and I have no clue how to do this. It does not delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are that `this` is not what you expect. Try:

```
'click .btn-danger'()
{
    let that = this;
    console.log(that._id);
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm){
      if (isConfirm) {
        Clanovi.remove(that._id);
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
      } else {
        swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
      }
    });

}
```

OR - you haven't setup your allow/deny rules to allow deletions on the client.

From a security pov you're better off calling a method to delete rather than doing it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what worked for me:

```
const answer = await swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#dd6b55',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d44',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, keet it',
  closeOnConfirm: false
})
```

And answer will have `{value: true}` if confirmed by user